# Ajax + php long pollinng get something wrong

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-integer, polling

I´m trying to do the ajax php polling function it seemed to work fine but I can´t understand what´s wrong or did I misunderstood something ?

Let´s see my code:

****In index.php****

```
  $tst = $conn->prepare('SELECT dtimestamp FROM inbx where recipient=:recipient  ORDER BY dtimestamp DESC LIMIT 1');

  $tst->bindParam(':recipient', $row['user_id']);
  $tst->execute();
  $rk= $tst->fetch();

<body onload="chkinbx(<?php echo $row['user_id']?>, <?php echo $rk['dtimestamp'] ?>);">
```

**In Javascript**

```
function chkinbx (user_id, cur_time) {

var old_timestamp=0;

var url="function.php?user_id="+user_id+"&cur_time="+cur_time;
var params="user_id="+encodeURIComponent(user_id)+"&cur_time="+encodeURIComponent(cur_time);


xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function () {

 if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){

var result=xmlHttp.responseText;
var res=JSON.parse(result);


if(res[2]==old_timestamp || cur_time==res[2]){

////  do nothing

}else{
    document.getElementById(bb).innerHTML="<a class='topNav' href='inbox.php'><span class='countmsg'>"+res[1]+"</span></a>";


}

setTimeout(function() {
chkinbx (res[3], res[4], cur_time);  // div   user_id   curtime

}, 1000); //8 seconds

 }
}
```

**In function.php**

```
$params=$_POST['params'];
$user_id=$_POST['user_id']; 
$cur_time=$_POST['cur_time'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT dtimestamp FROM inbx where recipient=:recipient AND inbxicn_is_click=:inbxicn_is_click  ORDER BY database_timestamp DESC' );
  $stmt->execute(array(':recipient'=>$user_id,':inbxicn_is_click'=>'N'));
  $r=$stmt->fetch();

while ($r['dtimestamp'] <= $cur_time) {
  sleep(10);
  clearstatcache();

 }

     $phpArray = array("ok",$stmt->rowCount(), $r['database_timestamp'], $user_id);
     echo json_encode($phpArray);
```

**It won´t work until I change to ($r['dtimestamp'] > $cur_time) ;**
**I wonder why ?**

Because the logic is $cur_time( which post from javascript is the original timestamp in index.php.
and $r['dtimestamp'] is the curent timstamp in database. This is the opposite from logic.

Comment: What do you mean wont work?

Comment: Ahh, I mean I will not get the result , sorry wrong writting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because until $r['dtimestamp'] > $cur_time you have told it to sleep 10 and do clearstatcache(),

```
while ($r['dtimestamp'] <= $cur_time) {
  sleep(10);
  clearstatcache();

 }
```

it is only once $r['dtimestamp'] > $cur_time that it gets out of your while loop and if $r['dtimestamp'] < $cur_time to start with it will never suddenly get > unless something in clearstatcache is changing $cur_time

Comment: Ok thank for answer. But do you think there´s something wrong in my code ? or do you have anything to suggest me to do it in the better way ?